# Will PostgreSQL 9 work with ArcGIS 10?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, postgresql

I realize it is not listed as a supported Database.  I am interested to see if anyone has tried to install and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is simple answer [here](http://events.esri.com/uc/QandA/index.cfm?fuseaction=answer&conferenceId=DD02CFE7-1422-2418-7F271831F47A7A31&questionId=3945) about supporting postgresql 9.

> **Will Esri support PostgreSQL 9 at 10.1?**
>
> Yes, PostgreSQL 9.0.2 will be supported at 10.1.

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 1):

Wait for ZigGIS 3.0 then you can edit without ArcSDE.

http://geobabble.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/ziggis-3-0-to-be-open-source/

It's still in development.

Comment: The current, commercial, version of zigGIS can edit PostGIS geometries now without ArcSDE. I don't think it's been tested with PostgreSQL 9 or the latest version of PostGIS yet, though.

Comment: ZigGIS is alive or dead? I try to find any information but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded it but there is no "free" win exe for it yet. So I began to learn how to build it on my win xp machine and decided to stick with the supported esri sde install. (which states that you are to use the postgres install on the sde dvd. 8.3) So that is where I am now.

Comment: What do you mean there is no win exe (all pure postgresql releases are free). https://www.enterprisedb.com/getfile.jsp?fileid=1518 has been there since release.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Am I mistaken? Every time I download and install an enterprisedb build I get the message to start my free 30 day trial. I see pricinig on their website. I have not been successful searching their website for install files like this.

Comment: have you seen postgis win install for 9?

Comment: The above link shouldn't give you a 30-day trial period. If you get that I think you have downloaded postgresql plus. That is why I wrote "pure" postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried either, but worst case scenario, you should be able to use the ODBC drivers and connect to that DB.

Comment: but you will never get the geometries through ODBC, only attribute data, right?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can call PostGIS functions in your SQL and return the geometries as WKT or WKB in your standard ODBC record set.