# ArcSDE desktop license

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

I am using the ArcGISDesktop student license. I want to work on versioning and geodatabase replication.

Is it possible to set up ArcSDE with the same license and work on versioning and replication?

Answer (score 6):

> [ArcSDE geodatabase options](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_comparison_of_geodatabase_types/003n00000024000000/)

### **There are two types of ArcSDE geodatabases:**

**ArcSDE for SQL Server Express**—ArcGIS Desktop at the ArcEditor and ArcInfo license levels, ArcGIS Engine, and ArcGIS Server Workgroup edition ship with SQL Server Express. You can install SQL Server Express, which is a lightweight, personal copy of SQL Server, and enable it to store geodatabases. With ArcCatalog, you can set up and administer a SQL Server Express instance as well as ArcSDE geodatabases, so you do not have to be a database administrator (DBA) to use these types of ArcSDE geodatabases. When licensed through ArcGIS Desktop or ArcGIS Engine, up to three users can connect to the SQL Server Express instance. When licensed through ArcGIS Server Workgroup, 10 desktop clients and any number of Web clients can connect to the SQL Server Express instance.
**ArcSDE geodatabases licensed under ArcGIS Server at the Enterprise level**—In addition, ArcSDE can work in enterprise settings across a range of DBMSs using ArcSDE Enterprise geodatabases. ArcSDE Enterprise is purchased as part of ArcGIS Server Enterprise level and typically requires DBA privileges and skills to set up and administer the underlying DBMS. See What is ArcSDE? for more information.

You can [set up](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_setting_up_and_using_database_servers/003n00000099000000/) personal sde with [sqlexpress](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/geodatabases/10.0/arcsde-installation-guides).
This provides limited replication.
Also limited editing connections.
[Here is a guide for installing and configuring.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/install_guides/arcgis_desktop_or_arcgis_engine_microsoft_sql_server_express_installation_guide/index.html)