# Editing PostGIS data in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, postgis, geoserver, wfs

Quick question regarding editing PostGIS data in ArcMap 10.0.  Far as I can tell, this can only be accomplished through third-party plugins like GISSquirrel or ST-Links.  Does anyone know of an alternative way that omits third-party involvement?

As an alternative, is it possible to edit remotely-hosted data served up in ArcGIS via a Geoserver WFS?  Again, the research I've done indicates you can view the data in ArcGIS, but no edit capabilities.

I have my data stored remotely in PostGIS and served through Geoserver.  Of course, I'm trying to find a way that allows editing of the data within the ArcGIS environment.  Well aware that I can do this in QGIS, just wondering why I can't find a solution for ArcGIS.