# Connect PostGIS with ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, postgresql-9.6, arcgis-10.4

I want to connect a PostGIS database to ArcMap 10.4. I work on Windows 7 with a PostgreSQL 9.6. Interoperability extension is installed and activated. I can see the PostGIS layers in the Catalog. I can see the field names of the layers. Even the preview works: [image]

And also in QGIS it works fine. 
But whenever I try to load one of these PostGIS layer into my project I get an error message: "Attribute column not found" and ArcMap does not show the feature geometries and the attribute columns:

[image]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147/connecting-to-postgis-database-from-arcmap-for-display-and-query-without-arcsde this question might help you

Comment: arc, from my experience does a very poor job at dealing with any changes you make to tables outside of an arcgis environment. I have received this error if I run a SQL script in pgadmin creating a table, then if I make modifications to this table by either overwriting it with different columns names or adding/subtracting columns, then there are many times this error pops up. You can try and use the add query layer (sometimes this a good workaround)

Comment: What user owns the table? Query Layers has zero tolerance for group role ownership or uppercase names. ArcGIS 10.4 does not support PostgreSQL 9.6. Please [edit] the question to specify the PostGIS version.

Comment: thanks for your comments. When I try query layer I get the same error message. Indeed I manipulated the tables outside of an arcgis environment. And yes, it seems that ArcGIS 10.4 does not support PostgreSQL 9.6. It would be handy to find an overview which ArcMap version supports which postgreSQL version.

Comment: Here is an overview which version of ArcGIS supports which version of PostgreSQL: http://desktop.arcgis.com/de/system-requirements/10.4/database-requirements-postgresql.htm There is a dropwodn on top of the page were you can switch to other ArcMap versions: 10.3 and 10.4 and 10.5.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you select Unique field for the query layer and fields are free of weird characters for ArcGIS desktop and fields are not longer than 32 characters.